# Why are there some Stack Exchange sites that are not registered by me, but shown in “my community” and can be accessed by me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, email

See my [Stack Exchange accounts tab here](https://stackexchange.com/users/30593831/user1176409?tab=accounts)

[image: picture]

[Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/119991/),
[Martial Arts Stack Exchange](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/13352/), and
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22722316/) are listed.

I don't know why these accounts are shown on the page (see image) above.

Moreover, not only can I see the profiles of these accounts, but I can also edit these user profiles (and delete their accounts).

I have double-checked the email addresses of these users and I can see that their email accounts aren't the same as my account, user1176409.

(See their email addresses to double check my email accounts haven't been used by others, not for bad purposes.)

What should I do about these accounts? Should I *ignore* them?

These users (I mean the accounts that is not registered by me) have changed all their usernames to user1176409……

UPDATE:
I think this problem has resolved. They ( I mean Stack Exchange Community Support Team) have emailed me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that it took so long was because the actions that were necessary to diagnose and un-do the original erroneous merge require manual intervention by one of a very few qualified staff members, none of whom report to me. We also needed input from several different teams on various parts of this (although in fairness, that didn't slow us down - they responded quickly).

In order to get this work done, we had to steal folks from other projects to remediate this (for which they have my undying gratitude and an IOU for adult beverages next time I see them).  We'll be retro'ing the situation to see what if anything we could have done to 1) avoid or prevent this and 2) to speed up our response.

I can only imagine the frustration you must be feeling. I want to assure you that the work was done as quickly as it could be safely executed, and we were able to use the very best possible folks to unravel the spiders web that was created. I am truly very sorry that it took as long as it did, and we'll be spending time ensuring that we never have to do it again.

Comment: "*an IOU for adult beverages next time I see them*": this part alone deserves an UV :D

Comment: I was raised right :)

Answer (score 4):

I reported this problem via [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) on Monday, February 12 at 2:33 AM, and this problem was resolved on Tuesday, February 21, 10 days after I reported this issue ( as I can access my accounts on that day).

The Stack Exchange Community Support Team emailed me when the issue was resolved.

**Why did it take so long for this account merging issue?**

**February 12 UPDATE**

> On Friday, a small number of accounts were actioned in error. Each of those accounts will have these actions reversed. Unfortunately, this is a VERY manual process. However, we started working on it as soon as the problem was identified.
>
> While the team is investigating it, you will not be able to log into the site. This is to ensure no changes are made to the account while checking to see what's gone on.

**February 15 UPDATE**

> I wanted to reach out and give you an update on the account merge issue. The engineering team is still working on fixing each account. It's proving to be a very manual process, so will take some more time.
>
> As a reminder, to ensure there are no changes to the account anyone that was affected has had their accounts locked.

**February 23 UPDATE**

> My apologies for the delayed update. You are able to access the account.